# ERROR :Could not load the script in /usr/local/lib64/kamailio//kamctl/kamdbctl.mysql for database engine MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, kamailio

I am getting this error when trying to create the database on kamailio. 
I've used the following command : **sudo /usr/local/sbin/kamdbctl create**.
  I've set the **DBENGINE=MYSQL** in kamctlrc file and saved as well. Still getting this error. Anyone please suggest me how to proceed. I've tried all possible ways but couldn't find the solution anywhere online.

**ERROR :Could not load the script in /usr/local/lib64/kamailio//kamctl/kamdbctl.mysql for database engine MYSQL
ERROR: database engine not loaded - tried 'MYSQL'**

Comment: First of all check your mysql server is running and then install mysql client. For ubuntu ; libmysqlclient-dev

Answer (score 0):

The file **kamdbctl.mysql** is installed when you install **db_mysql** module. Be sure that module is installed. Next is a sequence to get the module installed:

```
  make include_modules="db_mysql" cfg
  make all
  make install
```